# TimeSpan Windows Mobile 6 and WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf

I have an mobile application that connects to a wcf service to get data. One of the objects on the service side has a TimeSpan DataMember. Everything works fine except this field because it comes as a string:

Service      Mobile
04:00:00 --> "PT4H"

How can I get a TimeSpan from a wcf service?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any info on what PT represents ?

Comment: `P` is the duration designator, it stands for "period". `T` is the time designator, it indicates that what follows is the time component of the duration. If the date component is all zeroes, it is omitted and thus results in `PT` at the start. More: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. By default, `TimeSpan` is serialized as

```
XmlElementAttribute(DataType="duration")
```

This is a string like "PT4H".

To get the real value you have to use `XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan()` and it will return the actual timespan value.